# .keydown() when press return key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

I'm trying to get the option that when a user presses the Return key, the search button is triggered. 
Currently it can only be pressed on the search button, but sometimes users have the tendency to press the return key after the search entry.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search-button').keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode==13) {
       Trackster.searchTracksByTitle($("#search-input").val());
    }
  });
  $("#search-button").click(function(){
    Trackster.searchTracksByTitle($("#search-input").val());
  });
});
```

does anyone know what i did wrong here? i still cant use press return to trigger the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a search input and a search button, an ideal practice is to get them wrapped by a `form` tag.

```
<form id="search-form">
  <input type="text" id="search-input" ...>
  <button type="submit" id="search-button" ...>Search</button>
</form>
```

Notice that the `type` is set to `submit`. It makes the button act as a submit button for the form. Now you will have to listen to the `submit` event of the form. The *return* key binding comes for free. Plus, you don't have to listen to the `keydown` and `click` events separately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Trackster.searchTracksByTitle($("#search-input").val());
  })
});
```

You will see that the search works when:

1. User types something in textbox and hits the *return* key
2. User types something in textbox and clicks on the *submit* button

I believe this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have attached the `keydown` event on the `search-button` but in my opinion it has be attached on the `search-input`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search-input').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      Trackster.searchTracksByTitle($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $("#search-button").click(function() {
    Trackster.searchTracksByTitle($("#search-input").val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var $btn = $('#search-button');
  var $inElement = $btn.prev('input');
  $inElement.keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode==13) {
      Trackster.searchTracksByTitle($("#search-input").val());
    }
  });
  $btn.click(function(){
    Trackster.searchTracksByTitle($("#search-input").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: The whole idea is to get the actual input element. Change the code to use the input element's ID as that would be easier.